# Historical imperfections of (La)TeX

Tags: tex-core, syntax, tex-history

Assume for a moment that all TeX literature, TeX software, TeX files etc. got destroyed in some global cataclysm. All information about TeX survives only in the mind of a few TeX gurus, or something like that.

So we would be "free" to write a typesetting system from scratch, without any need for backward-compatibility holding us back, but using our knowledge about historical imperfections of (La)TeX, if any.

What might be the main differences between the current (La)TeX and the new typesetting system?

**Edit:** I'm not asking "what *will all* the differences be" or "what controversial opinions might circulate". Rather I'm asking "what differences are likely to be a *consensus*". If a historical site gets destroyed, there might be debate in which style to rebuild it, but there will be *consensus* that fire safety should correspond to modern strict standards, rather than historical standards.

<sub>I'm **asking this because** I'm wondering about certain aspects of the history of (La)TeX (hence the `tex-history` tag), specifically how imperfections were kept for historical reasons (e.g. need for backward-compatibility). Otherwise it's difficult to understand why certain aspects of (La)TeX exist but are deprecated or discouraged from being used; why (La)TeX is the way it is (complicated in some cases); how wrong the opinion is that a simpler-to-use but equally powerful typesetting system would be possible.</sub>

Comment: The question is much to broad and to opinion based. Assume that an arbitrary historic site on this world gets destroyed. Do you think you would get any two architects to agree on how to rebuild it?

Comment: I am not sure this question is answerable in the format of this site it is too broad and too opinion based

Comment: I edited the question to narrow it down and discourage opinions. Please let me know in case objections remain.

Comment: No need to guess anything. Just compare LaTeX with an  TeX-based system build from scratch ([SILE](https://sile-typesetter.org/) for example) and you will actually see the  positive (and negative) effects of cut ties with the history.

Comment: @Fran Huh, one of the two examples on the front page of the SILE site uses ` -- ` several places in the source and does not correctly turn them into em dashes. Not a good look.

Comment: @Davislor As I said, positive and **negative** effects of start from scratch.

Comment: @Davislor Actually that's a documented (not sure of good or bad) feature. See the very beginning of [section **3.2 Ordinary text**](https://sile-typesetter.org/manual/sile-0.9.5.pdf#dest16) of the manual.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Then they should show the right way in their examples?

Comment: @Davislor Quite possibly. Most likely the author wrote in SILE with TeX in mind ;-) I particularly find it very useful to have TeX's "funny ligatures" for dashes and quotes and... I can never find the proper unicode characters in my keyboard.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik They might also have copy-pasted some public-domain text from the Web.

Comment: I've started cataloging some of the things that I think LaTeX got wrong at https://www.finl.xyz/category/mistakes-of-latex/